# Why isn't $\cos(ωt + θ)$ included when calculating velocity for this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

The problem is;

> The ends of a tuning fork oscillate at a frequency of 440 Hz with an amplitude of 0.50 mm. Determine (a) the maximum velocity and (b) the maximum acceleration of
> the ends.

I know the answer involves taking the derivative of $x(t) = A\*cos(ωt + θ)$. But when calculating velocity and acceleration, only the A*ω / A/*ω^2 part is considered in the solution, not the cosine part. Why is that?

Comment: Because the question asks for the _maximum_ velocity and acceleration.

Comment: Penelope, note that the maximum value of the sine and cosine functions is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A\omega \text{ and} A\omega^2$ are the maximum of the velocity and acceleration so thats what is mentioned, but v(t) still is $v(t)=A\omega sin(\omega t+\phi)$